# Adding Classes to Appended Elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a CSS class to li tag that was appended to html after exercising jQuery ajax call. The goal is to add a left border to the appended li element when mouse cursor is over that element and remove the border when the border when mouse leaves the li element. However, the code does not execute and no border is added to the li tag.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#searchButton").on('click', function() {
    var searchValue = $('.form-control').val();
    var urlVar = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchValue + "&format=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: urlVar,
      contentType: "json",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(searchData) {
        $('#output').html(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < searchData[1].length; i++) {
          $('#output').prepend(searchData[1][i] + '<li id="listItems"><a href=' + searchData[3][i] + '>'  + searchData[2][i] + '</a></li>');
          $('#output a').attr('target', '_blank')
      }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Something is off, man!!!")
      }
    });
  });
  $('#listItems').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('listFormat');
  });
  $('#listItems').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('listFormat');
  });
});
```

My CSS:

```
listFormat {
 border-left: 5px black solid;
}
```

Just really not sure how to address this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First, why don't you just add the class when appending the item, and use proper css:`listFormat:hover`?

Comment: did you try to add that with only CSS ?

Comment: #listItems li:first-child { border-left: 1px solid red; }

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is probably that to listen for events on dynamically added elements you need to use the `on` method.

```
  $('#listItems').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('listFormat');
  });
  $('#listItems')on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('listFormat');
  });
```

Also though, as @junkfoodjunkie says, the technique you are proposing is perfectly viable but a little over-complicated because there is already a useful CSS tag that will apply a style when the mouse moves over an element. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp for a quick example.

Comment: Good point. The CSS:hover solution is much more elegant and easier to implement. Thanks.